# ODBC connection failure on Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, odbc, visual-foxpro

Hi I am using Windows 7 and Access 2013. I am unable to link tables using Visual Fox Pro DB via Access after a windows update. I get the error message : ODBC connection failed. In order to fix this where should I start exploring? I went to windows regedit-> ODBC->ODBCINST.INI and I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: How are your FoxPro and Access databases linked? What is your application? Are you using Access as a Forms/Reports frontend for a FoxPro ODBC source?

Comment: @Dai I am just trying to import  some tables from a FoxPro Database to Access so that I can write some queries to get the data I want.

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion, you should start from "data sources(ODBC)",
then create a User DSN, by selecting the correct driver 
Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver.

Then you can setup all needed information to create a ODBC connection to your Foxpro database. (I don't have FoxPro as it's not used in my company), but we do the same between MS Access and Oracle.

Once set, you can open your MS Access database and create linked tables towards your FoxPro database via the ODBC DSN just created.

good luck !